# When the DeleteEvent is called by a Gtk# window, how can I prevent the window from closing?

Tags: gtk#

When the window closes, the user is asked to save the file that they edited. They should also have an option to cancel quitting the application.

In WPF I can set the CancelEventArgs.Cancel property to true to do this. Is there an equivalent/workaround in Gtk#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the DeleteEventArgs.RetVal to **true**, not false. From the [relevant Mono documentation](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3AGtk.DeleteEventArgs):

To keep a `Gtk.Window` from closing, set `Gtk.DeleteEventHandler`'s `Gtk.DeleteEventArgs.RetVal` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this python example ([link](http://www.micahcarrick.com/files/gtk-glade-tutorial/PyGTK/tutorial.py)) from a quick google search:

```
# When the window is requested to be closed, we need to check if they have 
# unsaved work. We use this callback to prompt the user to save their work 
# before they exit the application. From the "delete-event" signal, we can 
# choose to effectively cancel the close based on the value we return.
def on_window_delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):

    if self.check_for_save(): self.on_save_menu_item_activate(None, None)
    return False # Propogate event
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Setting DeleteEventArgs.RetVal to false prevents the application from exiting but the window still disappears and calling ShowAll does not show it again.